# Internet speed reduction (on installed system) Kubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, kernel, kubuntu

I reinstalled my Kubuntu 18.04 system 3 weeks ago. I have installed updates in the last few days, then the internet speed has dropped 
significantly. **Instead of 250/20 Mbit, only 20/15 Mbit can be measured.** **For USB Live system does not have this phenomenon.**

On the live system, the 4.15.0-20-generic kernel runs while the currently installed 4.15.0-36-generic kernel is running, **trying to boot with the older kernel in GRUB, but the situation did not change**

uname -a: (live)
Linux kubuntu 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

uname -a: (installed)
Linux adam-desktop 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Config:

```
Motherboard: Asrock 960GM-GS3 FX
CPU: AMD Athlon II X2 250 3.00GHz AM3
NIC: TP-Link TG-3269 (Realtek RTL-8169SC chip)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on two my devices with Kubuntu 18.04.
In my case, speed has dropped from 100/100 Mbit to 10/100 Mbit. Execute command `ethtool -s <my_interface> autoneg on speed 100 duplex full` resolve this.
Before, auto-negotiation is off and duplex is half, changing NetworkManager settings has no effect on ethtool output and speed.
Before:

```
Settings for enx00e04c3605cc:
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  Not reported
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: No
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Half
Port: MII
PHYAD: 32
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: off
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00007fff (32767)
                   drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err tx_queued intr tx_done rx_status pktdata hw wol
    Link detected: yes
```

After:

```
Settings for enx00e04c3605cc:
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                     100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: MII
PHYAD: 32
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on

Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted    Current message level: 0x00007fff (32767)
                   drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err tx_queued intr tx_done rx_status pktdata hw wol   Link detected: yes
```

Comment: I have full duplex 1000 but speed in 50-100Mbit/s

`sudo ethtool enp2s6
Settings for enp2s6:
 Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
 Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
 ...
 Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
 Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
 ...
 Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full  
 100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full   1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
 Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
 ...
 Speed: 1000Mb/s    Duplex: Full   Port: MII
...
`

Comment: I think I will reinstall and block the kernel update soon, I hope to solve the problem.